# Rewriting URL on remote site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I manage 2 sites.
The first site '***foo.com***' is a virtual host with *Apache 2*, redirect to another site ('***1.2.3.4:1234***'), with *Nginx*.

I have used *Rewriterule*, *Redirect*... but the URL in the browser is converted always to '***1.2.3.4:1234***' when the redirect is done.

Can I keep the original URL ('***foo.com***')  somehow?

Thank you very match.

Note:
I probed the solution to post: [Redirect to other domain but keep typed domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain)

But I receive a 503 error code with the following logs:

```
...
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //1.2.3.4:1234/
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1540): [client 82.130.187.20] proxy: *: found reverse proxy worker for http://1.2.3.4:1234/
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1020): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1962): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://1.2.3.4:1234/
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2026): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (*)
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2082): proxy: connecting http://1.2.3.4:1234/ to 1.2.3.4:1234
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2209): proxy: connected / to 1.2.3.4:1234
[Thu Nov 06 20:50:06 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2460): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to *
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:06 2014] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 1.2.3.4:1234 (*) failed
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:06 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2044): proxy: HTTP: has released connection for (*)
82.130.187.20 - - [06/Nov/2014:20:50:06 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 406
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //1.2.3.4:1234/favicon.ico
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1540): [client 82.130.187.20] proxy: *: found reverse proxy worker for http://1.2.3.4:1234/favicon.ico, referer: http://foo.com/
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1020): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1962): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://1.2.3.4:1234/favicon.ico
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2026): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (*)
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2082): proxy: connecting http://1.2.3.4:1234/favicon.ico to 1.2.3.4:1234
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2209): proxy: connected /favicon.ico to 1.2.3.4:1234
[Thu Nov 06 20:51:08 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2460): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to *
[Thu Nov 06 20:52:08 2014] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 1.2.3.4:1234 (*) failed
[Thu Nov 06 20:52:08 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2044): proxy: HTTP: has released connection for (*)
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to other domain but keep typed domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901/redirect-to-other-domain-but-keep-typed-domain)

Comment: Yes, is very similar, but his solution not worked for me. I receive a 503 error code.

Comment: `The timeout specified has expired: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 1.2.3.4:1234 (*) failed` there is nothing on 1.2.3.4 that listens port 1234, or apache is not able to connect to that IP.

Comment: Is an example. Isn't the real address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many threads that cover your problem, you could try those:

[.htaccess redirect without changing address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304492/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-address-bar)

[Subdomain redirect with htaccess without changing URL in the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826921/subdomain-redirect-with-htaccess-without-changing-url-in-the-address-bar)

https://serverfault.com/questions/235879/keeping-the-original-subdomain-url-in-the-address-bar-with-wildcard-subdomains

Comment: None of them works for me. None of them keep the original URL.

Comment: Yes, Is right. I had a problem with the router. Is OK