# redirect subdomain to a page in my primary domain without changing url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a magento website mydomain.com

I have a page in my website called mydomain.com/mypage.html
,this mypage.html is not a file in my directory it is a magento cms page.

My issue is how can i redirect my subdomain mysub.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/mypage.html

I dont want the url in my web browser to change so that when i open mysub.mydomain.com i can see the page mydomain.com/mypage.html and all its included url ex: when i open mysub.mydomain.com/newpage i will be really opening mydomain.com/mypage/newpage.html

I need the correct htaccess rewrite rules, also i need to know what to do on my cpanel, do i add the subdomain as a subdomain or as an alias for the main website.
This didnt work for me:

```
this also didnt work:RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysub.example.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/newpage.html/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

It redirect the subdomain to newpage.html and the url in browser changed

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i am new to mod rewrites, tried many examples i found on internet nothing worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826921/subdomain-redirect-with-htaccess-without-changing-url-in-the-address-bar. didnt work and many others